# Deployment Descriptor and Java Resources gone

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

i don't know what exactly what is my problem. Yesterday when i create a new dynamic web application still had the complete form. Today all of this has gone. Create new project still the same problem. I have just change my work space's path. (Same folder but different name [D:\Eclipse Project\Workspace] to [D:\EclipseProject\Workspace]
Yesterday my project was like this (has deployment and resources)
[image]

But today, it's like this

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why are the icons for the projects different? Are both pictures of the same project?

Comment: not the same, because it has changed so i could not capture it, i use a picture in internet, the second is mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your perspective changed from JavaEE to Java within Eclipse.  I'm guessing you have it defaulted to the standard Java perspective.  This will impact the way projects are displayed (including the removal of deployment descriptor stubs).

To fix, click on window within the menu bar and select 'perspective' then 'open perspective'.  At this point, choose 'other' and select the JavaEE perspective.  Once Eclipse switches to that perspective, you will see the deployment descriptor stubs once again.

Answer (score 0):

try the following steps

select the menu `Window -> Show View -> Project View`

I think the problem may be caused by `chose a different view`

Comment: this can't fix that, i think the problem is not view, because all my projects is not dynamic web anymore. When i try to generate a web.xml by Java EE tool, this occurs "the chosen operation is not enable"

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue after so many attempt i found one easy and simple way to add diployment discriptor to project.

1. right click on project.
2. find (java EE Tools) and open it.
3. click on (Generate Diployment Discriptor Strub).

and you get your diployment discriptor.